# Ruby: Generate PDF from XML and XSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, pdf

is there a way to generate a PDF file using XML and XSL as stylesheet?
I need to do this from a Rails 4.0.0 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why the question was down-voted...

Anyway I found a way to do it. Here it is in case someone wonders the same some day.

```
document = Nokogiri::XML(File.read(Rails.root.to_s+'/lib/label.xml'))
template = Nokogiri::XSLT(File.open(Rails.root.to_s+'/lib/xsl_which_imports_more_xsl.xsl','rb'))
html_document = template.transform(document)

pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html_document)

save_path = Rails.root.join('public','filename.pdf')
File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
   file << pdf
end
```

Wicked_pdf might be able to do it without Nokogiri but this way it worked fine so I didn't spend more time on it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/
From within ruby you call it by executing a bash command. We use it in all our Rails projects.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I knew of fop but since I run on Heroku it looks quite hard to get it running there.